# model to explore correlation of pollution long-term exposure with genetic mutation rates

Tags: time-series, model-selection, multiple-comparisons, model, model-comparison

I have pollution data of several US cities, as example `NY`, `Boston`, and `Chicago`.
I need to compare levels of [PM2.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particulates), NO2 and O3 (continuous daily data) over the last 10 years in order to identify which city was most polluted in this long-term period, which least etc. and see if the long-term pollution exposure correlates with mutation rates in some specific genes (that I have for each sample).

Based on comments received, I think I could use *long term arithmetic mean* for each pollutant and each sample in a linear regression models with other variables (such as age, sex etc.).

I was wondering if there is some specific model used for this long-term exposure analysis. I have googled around and searched different scientific articles databases but could not find a precise answer on what method could be adequate for this comparison.

Thank you very much in advance for any help!

Comment: Start with a *scientific* definition: exactly what do you mean by "polluted" and how would you quantify it?  Then proceed to assessing your data; in particular, you need to evaluate how well they might represent air quality throughout those cities.  Then you will need to formulate a specific hypothesis.  This is potentially such a rich dataset that you will likely discover there is no fixed relationship among air quality conditions: sometimes one city is better, sometimes another city is better, and you should therefore think about a more detailed comparison.

Comment: Thank you @whuber for your detailed answer. My question was much more "basic": assuming that PM2.5 higher levels indicate a "worst" pollution, how do I weight it over time? I was wondering if there are some specific methods/models for that or I can simply average means over time etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, although your question might be basic, that doesn't make the correct answer any simpler: you still have to engage with these preliminary issues of establishing useful definitions and quantifications.  Otherwise any solution, although perhaps mathematically correct, will not have any assurance of providing reliable information about what really interests you, such as air quality, human health, etc.

Comment: Ok @whuber , thank you again, to be clearer, my hypothesis is that long-term exposure to irritant air pollutants (PM2.5, O3, and NO2) increases the mutation rates on some specific genes. I have mutation number for each sample on those genes and I need to put this in relationship with long-term exposure, of which I have daily data on the time frame under consideration, to see if the numbers of pollutants and mutations correlate

Comment: That's a good start, because it shows you need an estimate of long-term exposure.  Obviously, PM2.5 time series are only one ingredient in that calculation, which also requires information about who is exposed, how often, where they are located, and so on.  It's fair (and common) to make simplifying assumptions, at some risk of losing statistical power (thereby failing to detect the expected response).  The grossest such assumption would come down to using the *long term arithmetic mean* of PM2.5 as an exposure proxy.  Even then, there are many statistical issues likely to arise.

Comment: (Continued) Among them are that differences in monitoring methodologies and equipment can render data in different cities incomparable or at least require making adjustments.  Another is that such datasets usually have some missing periods or changes in monitoring frequency; these will require imputation (in the first case) and suitable weighting (in the second).  These are just some of the many reasons why we find it more helpful to answer *detailed, focused* questions: it helps us provide definite, correct answers instead of vague general advice.

Comment: Thank you again @whuber Would you suggest to use a *long term arithmetic mean* for each pollutant and each sample in a regression models with other variables (such as age, sex etc.)? I'll edit the question accordingly